# Organic Layer/Aqueous Layer Question

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I could not answer this question, it would be appreciated if someone could help.

> [image]

Comment: Lost in translation: hydroxyde de sodium pur ou solution aqueuse?

Comment: You could improve your question by adding what part of the question you understand, and where exactly you need help. Or you could give an example of a simpler question you already understand, or a worked example you are aware of.

Comment: @orthocresol Note that the OP did not ask for the answer to the question, but for help. I agree that some pointers about what parts of the question are clear to the OP and where the hurdles are would make the question much better. Also, this could lead to an actual question.

Comment: @KarstenTheis, (1) the interpretation of "help" is subjective: I read it as being "help me answer it". (2) that is part of the point of closing questions; it is not a final statement, if questions are edited, they will be reopened. It does not have to be OP who edits it, you can do it too, if you think that you can make it into a question that satisfies the community guidelines. (3) Fundamentally, all homework questions can lead to an actual question. That doesn't stop us from closing them.

Comment: In my experience, *right now* this question is a very clear-cut case where the question should be closed. If you disagree feel free to post on Meta where we can discuss in greater detail and solicit more opinions! Again, closure is not the end of a question; there is always the edit + reopen route.

Answer (score 1):

> it would be appreciated if someone could help

To answer this question, you need to know about liquid:liquid extraction, acid-base chemistry, and intermolecular interactions. These are the type of questions you would have to consider to answer your question:

**Extraction**: What is meant by sodium hydroxide as a solvent? What are the two layers? Which one is the aqueous layer?

**Acid-base chemistry**: Are the solutions neutral, acidic, basic, or something else? What form (as is, protonated, deprotonated) will species A-F be converted to in an acidic, neutral or basic solution? In other words, what acid-base reactions could occur between A-F and the extraction layers?

**Intermolecular interactions**: What intermolecular interactions can species A-F, in their various protonation states, have with the aqueous layer or with the other layer?

Once you are comfortable with these concepts and have answered or considered all these questions, you should be able to come to a conclusion.